# Twitter bootstrap: Nest input-prepend within pull-right and search form

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, google-chrome, twitter-bootstrap

The following code example code should result in something like [image: what it should look like].

```
<form class="well form-search">
  <div class="pull-right">
    <div class="input-prepend">
      <span class="add-on">
        <i class="icon-search"></i>
      </span>
      <input type="text" class="input-large search-query" />
    </div>
    <button class="btn" type="submit">Search</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

This works perfectly well in Firefox, but in both Chrome and Internet Explorer 7 browsers, it looks like the following:

[image: what it looks like in chrome]

Am I doing something "illegal" with bootstrap? I did not make any adaptions yet so it's completely out-of-the-box.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was a reported issue: https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/issues/1362

The fix outlined by tonybolzan in the issue works best because you don't have explicitly set a  width:

```
.input-prepend, .input-append {
    white-space: nowrap;
    -webkit-padding-end: 27px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with the whitespace found in your markup, try to place the `span` tag on the same line as the input, like so:

```
<form class="well form-search">
  <div class="pull-right">
    <div class="control-group">
        <div class="input-prepend">
            <span class="add-on"><i class="icon-search"></i></span><input type="text" class="input-large search-query" />
        </div>
        <button class="btn" type="submit">Search</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Unfortunately, this does not seem to fix the problem – I have removed all the whitespaces and am still having the problem...

Comment: @Remo Are you by any chance zooming in in your page? I tested it in IE7/8 Chrome Canary build/Chrome17 and Firefox11 and everything works fine. The only instance of the form breaking is when i resize my screen. I used this fiddle to test: http://jsfiddle.net/dDtUg/

Comment: Thanks for the example. But in our case, it does still not work (and I'm not zooming at all). Am I doing some illegal nesting? The code provided can be found under `body > .container > .row > .span12`. Any idea?

Comment: @Remo per documentation, your code looks fine with the update i made above so everything should look alright, i just can't think of anything that would cause your search bar to break like that. Has the bootstrap been modified in any way? Can you post a test page so i can take a look? I tested the fiddle i posted above and everything works fine so it must be something else surrounding the search form.

Answer (score 0):

This is old, but it helped me determine the answer I was looking for:

The problem is probably that bootstrap is setting the width of the input to 210px, which is causing the whole icon/input/button grouping to be wider than your well.

I've updated the fiddle Andres posted above with a sample of the problem by forcing the well forms to a smaller width than their default and a fix by using an input class with a smaller width.

http://jsfiddle.net/dDtUg/2/